# WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed for Flickr API

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, rest

I'm new to python and is learning REST API from an online material, which provided an example code for Flickr API.

The code worked in the online video, however when I tried to run the same code on my own computer environment (Windows, Python IDE installed, browser is Chrome), it gave me a time-out error 10060.

I also checked against the Flickr documentation to make sure all the parameters input are correct.

Anyone knows why and how I can solve it? Thank you.

```
import json
flickr_key = 'xxxxxxxxx' #my own key was keyed in here 

def get_flickr_data(tags_string):
    baseurl = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/"
    params_diction = {}
    params_diction["api_key"] = flickr_key # from the above global variable
    params_diction["tags"] = tags_string # must be a comma separated string to work correctly
    params_diction["tag_mode"] = "all"
    params_diction["method"] = "flickr.photos.search"
    params_diction["per_page"] = 5
    params_diction["media"] = "photos"
    params_diction["format"] = "json"
    params_diction["nojsoncallback"] = 1
    flickr_resp = requests.get(baseurl, params = params_diction, timeout=1800)
    # Useful for debugging: print the url! Uncomment the below line to do so.
    print(flickr_resp.url) # Paste the result into the browser to check it out...
    return flickr_resp.json()

result_river_mts = get_flickr_data("river,mountains")

# Some code to open up a few photos that are tagged with the mountains and river tags...

photos = result_river_mts['photos']['photo']
for photo in photos:
    owner = photo['owner']
    photo_id = photo['id']
    url = 'https://www.flickr.com/photos/{}/{}'.format(owner, photo_id)
    print(url)
    # webbrowser.open(url)
```

The error is like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TimeoutError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
D:\Python\Python Install\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py in _new_conn(self)
    168         try:
--> 169             conn = connection.create_connection(
    170                 (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw

D:\Python\Python Install\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address, socket_options)
     95     if err is not None:
---> 96         raise err
     97 

D:\Python\Python Install\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address, socket_options)
     85                 sock.bind(source_address)
---> 86             sock.connect(sa)
     87             return sock

TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] 

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

NewConnectionError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
D:\Python\Python Install\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    698             # Make the request on the httplib connection object.
--> 699             httplib_response = self._make_request(
    700                 conn,

D:\Python\Python Install\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    381         try:
--> 382             self._validate_conn(conn)
    383         except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError) as e:

D:\Python\Python Install\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in _validate_conn(self, conn)
   1009         if not getattr(conn, "sock", None):  # AppEngine might not have  `.sock`
-> 1010             conn.connect()
   1011 

D:\Python\Python Install\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py in connect(self)
    352         # Add certificate verification
--> 353         conn = self._new_conn()
    354         hostname = self.host

D:\Python\Python Install\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py in _new_conn(self)
    180         except SocketError as e:
--> 181             raise NewConnectionError(
    182                 self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e

NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000000056C9430>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

MaxRetryError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
D:\Python\Python Install\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    438             if not chunked:
--> 439                 resp = conn.urlopen(
    440                     method=request.method,

D:\Python\Python Install\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    754 
--> 755             retries = retries.increment(
    756                 method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]

D:\Python\Python Install\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py in increment(self, method, url, response, error, _pool, _stacktrace)
    573         if new_retry.is_exhausted():
--> 574             raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
    575 

MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.flickr.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /services/rest/?api_key='xxxxxxx' (#here masked by myself) &tags=river%2Cmountains&tag_mode=all&method=flickr.photos.search&per_page=5&media=photos&format=json&nojsoncallback=1 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000000056C9430>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] '))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ConnectionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-01e73ed2c8b4> in <module>
     25     return flickr_resp.json()
     26 
---> 27 result_river_mts = get_flickr_data("river,mountains")
     28 
     29 # Some code to open up a few photos that are tagged with the mountains and river tags...

<ipython-input-40-01e73ed2c8b4> in get_flickr_data(tags_string)
     20     params_diction["format"] = "json"
     21     params_diction["nojsoncallback"] = 1
---> 22     flickr_resp = requests.get(baseurl, params = params_diction, timeout=1800)
     23     # Useful for debugging: print the url! Uncomment the below line to do so.
     24     print(flickr_resp.url) # Paste the result into the browser to check it out...

D:\Python\Python Install\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py in get(url, params, **kwargs)
     74 
     75     kwargs.setdefault('allow_redirects', True)
---> 76     return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
     77 
     78 

D:\Python\Python Install\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py in request(method, url, **kwargs)
     59     # cases, and look like a memory leak in others.
     60     with sessions.Session() as session:
---> 61         return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
     62 
     63 

D:\Python\Python Install\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    540         }
    541         send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 542         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    543 
    544         return resp

D:\Python\Python Install\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in send(self, request, **kwargs)
    653 
    654         # Send the request
--> 655         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    656 
    657         # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)

D:\Python\Python Install\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    514                 raise SSLError(e, request=request)
    515 
--> 516             raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
    517 
    518         except ClosedPoolError as e:

ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.flickr.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /services/rest/?api_key=xxxxxxxx(#here masked by myself)&tags=river%2Cmountains&tag_mode=all&method=flickr.photos.search&per_page=5&media=photos&format=json&nojsoncallback=1 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000000056C9430>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] '))
```

Comment: Have you search for that error number online?

Comment: @Ulrich Eckhardt yes I have searched for the time out error, and tried various methods including adding a header (still same error), adding a timeout parameter (either result in same error if I set for longer time, or have no result if I set for a short time)